# Update drop down with javascript

Tags: javascript, electron, pouchdb

I am working on simple desktop billing  application using Electron js and pouch db

here is my html code

```css
function dbsubmit(){
     var Sno =  document.getElementById('number').value ;
     var date =   document.getElementById('date').value ;
     var Time =   document.getElementById('time').value ;
     

     var doc = {
          _id: Sno,
          Date: date,
          time: Time,
                
     };
     db.put(doc, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
          } else {
             console.log("Document created Successfully",response);
          }
     });
     
 
     

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bill System</title>
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bill</h1>

    <form>
        <label for="sno">S.NO</label>
        <select name="sno" id="number">
            
        </select>
        
        <label for="fname">Name : </label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="dtime" >
        <label for="fname">age : </label>
        <input type="text" id="time" name="dtime" >
        
        <input type="button" id=billsub  value="Save"/>      
        

    </form>

<script src="./db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is

when i first save the form the values will be 
sn.no - 1
name - xxx
age - yyy

after saving form the `s.no` select box should be automatically updated with `number 2` option

anyone help me with code

Comment: Where is your JS code for handling the form submit? The HTML page will update if the page reloads or some functions triggers the update.

Comment: added  js  please check

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp to add new options to your select programmatically

Comment: @JonathanHamel bro i want to add on form submit and also want to update the option to next number

Comment: Yes, you can do it in your db.put callback without a problem.

Comment: but on reloading entire application  the number will not updating to drop down can you help e with code

Comment: @Dineshkarthik Where are you loading the values for the select list?

Comment: i want to load the all id from db and display it in dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following snippet(I only test it without the db logic since you only want to update the html element):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.addEventListener('submit', dbsubmit);
function dbsubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var Sno =  document.getElementById('number').value ;
     var date =   document.getElementById('date').value ;
     var Time =   document.getElementById('time').value ;
     //Get select element here
     var select = document.getElementById('number');
     var doc = {
          _id: Sno,
          Date: date,
          time: Time,
     };
     //Do your db logic here to save the actual data
      db.put(doc, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
          } else {
            //Updating the html if the data is saved
              var opt = document.createElement('option');
              opt.value = ++doc._id;
              opt.innerHTML = opt.value;
              select.appendChild(opt);
              opt.selected = true
            
            console.log("Document created Successfully",response);
          }
     }); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bill System</title>
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bill</h1>

    <form id="form1">
        <label for="sno">S.NO</label>
        <select name="sno" id="number" value="1">
            <option id="snoValue" value="1" selected>1</option>
        </select>
        
        <label for="fname">Name : </label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="dtime" >
        <label for="fname">age : </label>
        <input type="text" id="time" name="dtime" >
        
        <input type="submit" id=billsub value="Save"/>      
        

    </form>

<script src="./db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i want all the ids in drop down for future edit for example if you saved 10 bills and you want to edit the 5 th bill so we want to select the 5 id in dropdown to get the values based on id hoe it clears

Comment: if you want to select the ids in future, just create new option and appended to select dropdown.  But, I do recommend to give a unique id for each options based on the value,(ex. option1 -> id="sno1"), so you can use either a for loop or DOM to select the option and data you want. Please try the updated snippet.

Comment: snippet is correctly working on submit the drop down is updated to next number after submit but a small problem after refreshing the application the dropdown is coming with number 1 only for mulitple times second number does not comes can you help me to clear

Comment: The reason for this issue could've been your db logic because after you reload the page. the counting starts from 1 again and you trying to store a new value for SNO.1 which is already exist, so your insertion of the new value could be failed, but the counting still continues.   The correct solution for this application should be. 1. Check the database if contains any value/records. 2.Update the dropdown with the latest/max SNO number _id. 3. Either select a exist SNO _id to change the exist value or have an option to append new record.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to want to keep the programs state in variables, then render it as html.  The code above treats the menu like the state; like it is the holder of the values.  Frameworks like ReactJS maintain state and render the html when the state changes; this one way data-flow makes the program fast and makes rendering smooth.  So something like this;

```
// keep a list of all the values in the menu; this is the state
// when editing the menu, update this menu state, then
// use it to redraw the select menu completely.
// (so the 'click' handler of your save button should do that)
var menuState = [];

const selectElement = document.getElementById('number');
const dateInput =   document.getElementById('date') ;
const timeInput =   document.getElementById('time') ;

function menuHandler(event) {
     var dateValue =   dateInpt.value ;
     var timeValue =   timeInput.value ;
     // TODO: validate these values
     
     menuState.append({date: dateValue, time: timeValue});
     enforceMenuState();  
}

function clearSelectOptions(select) {
    if (select) {
        while (select.options.length > 0) {
            select.remove(0);
        }
    }
}
function enforceMenuState() {
    // clear menu, the recreate it
    clearSelectOptions(selectElement);
    for (let i = 0; i < menuState.length; i += 1) {
        // create option element and add it to menu
        itemState = menuState[i];
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = `name: ${itemState.name}, age: ${itemState.age}`;
        option.value = i;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

NOTE: it's even better if you set a flag when state changes, then check that in a requestAnimationFrame() callback, and call enforceMenuState() in that callback if the state has changed, so that rendering happens when the browser is ready.  I used that technique in this [code](https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/f63b41a0991224da479492120750ac0e8ca0e4ee/client/js/turtle_view_controller.js#L74); updateView() is called by requestAnimationFrame().  The state is held in a RollbackState() object, which keeps track of the state change flags for each field.  If a field is 'dirty', then it will trigger a re-render.  That is all plain JavaScript.